# Regex-How can I filter out any grouping of 3 numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text below:

```
404 0 0 1674 3866 0
```

My goal is to capture any grouping of 3 numbers without a whitespace at the end, so that regex knows Im only looking for a group of 3 numbers starting with a number and ending with a number, no whitespaces before or after first and last digit.

This is what Ive come up with so far:

```
 /^(\d{3}\s)
```

This captures the first 3 numbers (404) and the whitespace. The $ does not help.

Comment: Remove the `\s` from the matching group

Comment: `\b\d{3}\b`, `(?<!\S)\d{3}(?!\S)`, etc.

Comment: `^` is the beginning of the string, so you don't want that. It means you'll only capture the one at the beginning. A `$` means end of the string. You wouldn't want that either unless you were specifying match that only occurred at the end.